# actualizar datos de una tabla a partir de otra en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Me gustaría saber si es posible, y cómo se hace, para actualizar datos de una tabla por otros de otra.

Por ejemplo:

La tabla 1:

```
id_tabla1 | Nombre | Descripcion
```

La tabla 2:

```
id_tabla2 | Nombre | Descripcion
```

La diferencia entre la tabla 1 y la 2, es que la 1 tiene los 2 primeros registros que no se pueden tocar, es decir, deben quedar fijos siempre, sí o sí.

La tabla 2 se actualiza todos los días (Se agregan y modifican datos)
Lo que necesito es insertar todos los datos de la tabla 2 en la 1.
Ya sea insertando los nuevos y actualizando los viejos, o bien borrando todos los datos de la tabla 1 menos los 2 primeros registros y luego insertar los de la tabla 2.

¿Se puede hacer?

La tabla 1 está en MYSQL y la 2 en SQL Server. Las tengo relacionadas, es decir, desde sql server hago las consultas de las tablas de mysql. Un ejemplo sería:

```
id_tabla1 | Nombre | Descripcion  
1                  a               a1  
2                  b               b1  
3                  c               c1
```

La tabla 2:

```
id_tabla2 | Nombre | Descripcion
1                  a               a1
2                  b               b1
3                  c               c2
4                  d               d1
```

Entonces lo que necesito es insertar en la tabla 1 la línea de id 4 de la tabla 2 y actualizar la línea del id 3.

Answer (score 2):

Esta solución es para dos tablas de **MySql**. Para empezar, te daré tablas con datos de prueba, para que se entienda.

[image]

Como has comentado, los dos primeros registros no se pueden borrar. Partiendo de esto, yo no me complico la vida y borro todos los registros de la tabla 1 menos esos dos, con esta query.

```
DELETE FROM Tabla_1 WHERE IdT1 <> 0 OR IdT1 <> 1;
```

Ahora bien, tienes tu tabla 1 limpia, solo te queda copiar todos los registros de la Tabla 2 en la Tabla 1, imaginemos la Tabla 2, tal que:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para copiar todos los registros, usas esta query:

```
INSERT INTO Tabla_1 SELECT * FROM Tabla_2;
```

Controlar los errores, eso ya como tu aplicación funcione.

> Un mejor control para evitar error de PK en tabla 1 al insertar datos
>   de Tabla 2. Usas esta query.

```
INSERT INTO Tabla_1 SELECT * FROM Tabla_2 WHERE IdT2 <> 0 OR IdT2 <> 1;
```

Te aseguras que si existe algún registro con Id con valor de 0 o 1 en la tabla 2, no se introduzca, ya que no te hacen falta, ya que has dicho que los dos primeros registros de la Tabla 1 no se tocan, y así te evitas el error de PK con Tabla 1.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Ahora te hago otra consulta, los ID de la tabla 2, se respetan cuando hago el insert en la tabla 1??

Comment: Los Id de la Tabla 2 se respetan, excepto si tienen el valor de IdT2=0 o IdT2=1, ya que te daría error de coherencia de PK en la Tabla 1.

Comment: Acabo de editar y añadir información al final de mi respuesta. Te ayudará.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @FIPS ¿Cómo has generado esas tablas? (Me refiero al dibujo)

Comment: Ahh pues esa una app on-line que se llama: **Cacoo**, te sirve para realizar diagramas UML, Web, etc, pero puedes usarla para lo que quiras.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que podrías añadir un atributo a esos registros que sea obligatorio y que te sirviera para las consultas a modo de `boolean`, de modo que si ese valor es 0 el registro no se puede borrar y si es 1 sí.

De esta forma harías un `delete` de todos los registros donde `campo = 1`, y luego insertas los valores que quieras y añades el valor 0 / 1 dependiendo si en el futuro lo vas a querer borrar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolvería con dos consultas. Primero un update actualizando todos los que crucen y luego otra query con una insert de los que no tienes en la primera. Intentar resolverlo en una sola consulta te va a complicar la vida en exceso.Te he construido unas sql con la estructura que muestras (al vuelo). Espero que te sirvan como referencia:

```
update tabla1 
set nombre = tabla2.nombre, 
descripcion = tabla2.descripcion 
from tabla1 
inner join tabla2 on tabla1.id = tabla2.id; 

insert into tabla1(id,nombre,descripcion) 
select tabla2.id,tabla2.nombre,tabla2.descripcion 
from tabla2 
left join tabla1 on tabla1.id=tabla2.id 
where tabla1.id is null;
```

Comment: Te he construido unas sql con la estructura que muestras (al vuelo). Espero que te sirvan como referencia:

Comment: update tabla1 set 
nombre = tabla2.nombre,
descripcion = tabla2.descripcion
from tabla1
inner join tabla2 on tabla1.id = tabla2.id;

insert into tabla1(id,nombre,descripcion)
select id,nombre,descripcion
from tabla2
left join tabla1 on tabla1.id=tabla2.id
where tabla1.id is null;